# See GoogleDrive files on ListView of my app

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I'm trying to build an app that should show user's files on the ListView, i've seen 2 video tutorial on Google Developers but at the end they don't explain nothing of i wanted know. Can someone explain me (maybe with code or some web example) how i can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to connect to connect to a user's gDrive, also at the left there is a menu with all information you would need.. Authorize Requests, API Reference, Developer Guides and alot more.. ;)

**QuickStart** - [https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android](https://developers.google.com/drive/)
**StartPage** - https://developers.google.com/drive/

~Max